# telegraf inherit variables from another file

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have a Telegraf configuration file that I've arranged to work on multiple servers. Unfortunately on every server I have to make a slight change to some fields.
Problem is that whenever I make an addition or a change to a configuration file, I must do so on all deployed versions of the same file.

I was wondering if it were possible to have a baseline file that accepts template variables (more or less Jinja-style) which I can get from an external file of whichever format.

I know I can use environment variables, I just would like to keep it as fallback option for the moment.

At the moment I have N copies of the same file.